# Using clustered covariance matrix in predict.lm()

Tags: r

I am analyzing a dataset in which data is clustered in several groups (towns in regions). The dataset looks like:

```
R> df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), 
                     y = 3*rnorm(x), 
                     groups = factor(sample(c('0','1'), 10, TRUE)))
R> head(df)
        x     y groups
1 -0.8959  1.54      1
2 -0.1008 -2.73      1
3  0.4406  0.44      0
4  0.0683  1.62      1
5 -0.0037 -0.20      1
6 -0.8966 -2.34      0
```

I want my lm() estimates to account for intraclass correlation in groups and for that purpose I am using a function `cl()` that takes an `lm()` and returns the robust clustered covariance matrix (original [here](http://people.su.se/~ma/clustering.pdf)):

```
cl  <- function(fm, cluster) {
  library(sandwich)
  M <- length(unique(cluster))   
  N <- length(cluster)              
  K <- fm$rank                   
  dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K-1))
  uj  <- apply(estfun(fm), 2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum));
  vcovCL <- dfc * sandwich(fm, meat = crossprod(uj)/N)
  return(vcovCL)
}
```

Now,

```
output <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
clcov <- cl(output, df$groups)
coeftest(output, clcov, nrow(df) - 1)
```

gives me the estimates I need. The problem now is that I want to use the model for prediction, and I need the standard error of the prediction to be calculated with the new covariance matrix `clcov`. That is, I need

```
predict(output, se.fit = TRUE)
```

but using `clcov` instead of `vcov(output)`. Something like a `vcov() <-` would be perfect.

Of course, I could write my own function to do predictions, but I am just wondering whether there is a more practical method that allows me to use methods for signature `lm` (like arm::sim).

Comment: You need to specify a bit more. What is that cluster function to start with? Why are the standard errors coming out of lm() not valid? I can't really follow what you try to do. It might very well be you need a more generalized model, eg glm, glmm or gam/gamm. There is very little left to do on standard errors of simple lm functions, unless you use them in a completely different context. But then we need the context...

Comment: @Joris I have edited the question. Hope it is clearer now. Please, note that I am explicitly avoiding a `glmm` model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The se.fit in predict is not calculated using the vcov matrix, but using the qr decomposition and the residual variance. This goes for the vcov() function as well: it takes the unscaled cov matrix from the summary.lm() together with the residual variance, and uses those ones. And the unscaled cov matrix is - again- calculated from the QR decomposition.

So I'm afraid the answer is "no, there is no other option than to write your own function". You can't really set the vcov matrix, as it is recalculated when needed. Yet, writing your own function is rather trivial.

```
predict.rob <- function(x,clcov,newdata){
    if(missing(newdata)){ newdata <- x$model }
    m.mat <- model.matrix(x$terms,data=newdata)
    m.coef <- x$coef
    fit <- as.vector(m.mat %*% x$coef)
    se.fit <- sqrt(diag(m.mat%*%clcov%*%t(m.mat)))
    return(list(fit=fit,se.fit=se.fit))
}
```

I didn't use the predict() function to avoid unnecessary calculations. It wouldn't shorten the code too much anyway.

---

On a side note, questions like this are better asked on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6):

I modified the above code slightly to be more consistent with the predict function--this way you are not expected to enter values for the outcome in the newdata dataframe

```
predict.rob <- function(x,clcov,newdata){
if(missing(newdata)){ newdata <- x$model }
tt <- terms(x)
Terms <- delete.response(tt)
m.mat <- model.matrix(Terms,data=newdata)
m.coef <- x$coef
fit <- as.vector(m.mat %*% x$coef)
se.fit <- sqrt(diag(m.mat%*%clcov%*%t(m.mat)))
return(list(fit=fit,se.fit=se.fit))}
```