# Predict se.fit using a multiway cluster robust vcov in GLM models to plot proper confidence intervals

Tags: r, glm, predict, standard-error, robust

I would like to plot the predictions of my probit model and include the 95% confidence interval based on the twoway clustered standard errors that I obtained using cluster.vcov()-function from the multiwaycov package.

However, the predict-functions that are out there do not allow me to pass them my correct variance-covariance-matrix and it seems a workaround is necessary (see workaround for lm-models by [Joris Mey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428790/joris-meys) and [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174421/michael) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793955).

Does anyone have an idea to go about this for probit (glm-models)? Or, are there other ways to go about this?